# excel vba - transferring multiline cell content to multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel, my requirement is to transfer multiline cell content to multiple rows. I have attached some sample input data and output data. Please let me know on how to proceed. Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: What have you done so far? I suggest you go from the last row of the name column until the top, check if the cell is empty and if so you copy the value from the previous cell. Try to do something and if it does not work, show it to us

Comment: You'll need to use the split function by chr(10) or chr(13)  best to try something first and post what you've done though.

Answer (score 0):

Select column "name" then use Ctrl+G->bank->type "=" then hit down arrow and Ctrl +Enter-> all blank cells will be filled as shown as ur output data ( unmerge first if column "name" contains merged cells )

Comment: Welcome to SO, Thanks for participating! Please read [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). I have removed opinions and personal comments, these should be added in comments.